# Login system with username and password from different tables, how to select from?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have searched for quite a while now about the possibility of having two tables (one for username and one for password) but haven't found anything useful.

I have two tables linked together with Primary Key and Foreign Key. One containing the username and one containing the password.

My current code is only for one table, like this:

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT membersid FROM members
   WHERE user='{$_POST['user']}'
   AND pass='{$_POST['passwd']}'");
```

Is there anyway I can use like equi joins together with input in my form?

All I got is this:

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT adminuser.userid, adminpass.passid 
   FROM adminuser, adminpass
   WHERE username='{$_POST['user']}'
   AND password='{$_POST['passwd']}'");
```

I know it's probably completely wrong, and I searched for an answer but haven't found one, that's why I'm turning here for help.

Is there anyway to solve my problem?

Comment: May I know why are you doing this. Why two tables for user and pass?

Comment: where is the mapping between the two table?

Comment: You need to ad another condition `and adminuser.userid = adminpass.userid` at the end.

Comment: @AliGajani I know it's not necessary but it's a school assignment to use relations between tables and this is the only thing I can use without screwing up my application.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but here's my 0.02 cents. You are missing this.

```
ON adminuser.userid=adminpass.userid;
```

[image]

Or maybe, this is more easy to understand.

`INNER JOIN` is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them.

```
SELECT adminuser.userid, adminpass.passid
FROM adminuser
INNER JOIN adminpass
ON adminuser.userid=adminpass.userid;
```

Comment: It isn't working but I'm afraid it might be correct but my problem is in the part of my code where I use fetch_assoc etc. to be able to use header(location: secretpage.php). I saw your edit now, but where should the $_POST be?

Comment: I have just given you a general idea of how to approach Inner Joins. I might edit my answer to incorporate your post data. Also, I invite anyone else to edit it further if there's anything else that lacks. :)

Comment: Ok I see, I'll try figuring out the inner joins then, thank you for the help!